# Canvas Size HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want to dynamically resize the canvas size according to the content of a DIV. i am using the following Code but it doesn't seems to work.

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="2000"  > <canvas>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("canvas1").style.height = document.getElementById("div").style.height;
document.getElementById("canvas1").style.width= document.getElementById("div").style.width;
```

Also i want that the canvas is loaded automatically , How should i do that ? on a `$(document).ready` event ?

How shall i do that too ?

Comment: what do you mean by loaded automatically?

Comment: I meant that  as soon as the page loades the following size is achieved

Comment: Put your resizing code in a function and call that function in response to body resize events as well as once on document ready or window onload.

Comment: I did that but it did'nt Work  :(

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Because `$(document).ready` is jQuery code, but your example is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth) to get the dimensions of the element (including borders).

```
// loaded automatically on page load
window.onload = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    canvas.height = div.offsetHeight;
    canvas.width  = div.offsetWidth;
}
```

Comment: It works Great, but the image which is already there on the canvas gets Pixelated , the image also expands. i want that the size of the image which is drawn on the canvas remains unchanged

Comment: @AdiMathur Then change the `.width/height` of the canvas; you'll also need to redraw the contents then.

Comment: I am ready to draw again but the statement dosnt work....

canvas.height = div.offsetHeight + "px";
canvas.width  = div.offsetWidth  + "px";

Comment: i want the drawing ratio to the canvas be 1 : 1

Comment: @Adi - Alright I didn't know about images. CSS dimensions are not good then. You should use `width/height` but **without** `px`. See my update.